# Using jQuery shake effect on document ready

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have an element on my page shake when the page loads. I would only like it to shake briefly(about 2 seconds) like when a username and password is incorrect on some sites.

Here is what I have tried.

```
       <div id="login_wrapper">

         <div id="login_header"><div id="header_title">Enter your login details below</div> </div>

         <div id="login_input_wrapper">

         <div id="username_wrapper">

           <div id="username_label"><h3>Username</h3></div><div id="username_input"><input type="text" class="text_field" id="login_username" name="login_username" placeholder="username123"></div>

         </div>

        <div id="username_wrapper">

          <div id="username_label"><h3>Password</h3></div><div id="username_input"><input type="password" class="text_field" id="login_password" name="login_password" placeholder="itsasecret"></div>

        </div>


      <div id="" class=""> <button class="login_button" value="submit"> login </div>


    </div>


  </div>

    </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#login_wrapper" ).effect( "shake" );
});

  </script>
```

I have placed this just before the end of the body in the document, but am getting no response. I'm new to jQuery, can anyone help me see whats wrong with my code please?

Comment: I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1ya48rp/) to show that this is possible

Comment: well i think you are looking for this http://www.9lessons.info/2014/07/ajax-php-login-page.html and demo http://demos.9lessons.info/ajaxLoginServer/index.php

Comment: just type the wrong username or password you will get a shake effect in the demo link

Answer (score 2):

`.effect()` is part of jQueryUI. You have to load jQuery and jQueryUI (in that order) to make it work.

[Check jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/dtyw59x1/)

Comment: Thank you. I have the UI source in that order. Still not working though.

Comment: The jsFiddle works. So, you have something wrong in your code. Can you post the console log?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="login_wrapper">Hello</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( "#login_wrapper" ).effect( "shake" );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure you loaded following. Just check your console for the error

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have the UI source in that order. Still not working though.

Comment: TypeError: $(...).effect is not a function

Comment: have loaded the jQuery UI and CSS too.

Comment: added the element. My src are exactly the same as you have put above.

Comment: If `TypeError: $(...).effect is not a function` probably jQuery UI is not loaded. Please, show us your `<head>` contents.

Comment: Make sure no other jquery libraries are loading on your page. Recommending to follow the structure of above code